# How do I achieve single sign on and data sharing across 2 rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on

I am looking to set up 2 rails apps (with the same tld) which have single sign on and share some user data. If I have railsapp.com I will have the second app set up as otherapp.railsapp.com or railsapp.com/otherapp. I will most likely have railsapp.com handle registration/login etc (open to suggestion if this is not the best solution).

So lets say I sign up and upload an avatar and start accumulating user points on the main-app, I can then browse to the other-app and my profile there has the correct avatar and points total. is there an easy way to achieve this? Do the available SSO solutions create the user in the second app with the same user ID? if not, how are they tied together? (ie how can I query the other app for information I would like to be shared across the 2 - user points and avatar) I was initially looking at sharing a database or at least the user table between the 2 apps, but I can't help thinking there must be an easier solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution is if you set the cookie on the `.railsapp.com` domain, then it should be sent when you do requests to `otherapp.railsapp.com` or **any other subdomain** (just stressing that as it might be a security concern). Remember to mark the cookie as secure!

And a extra bit you might need to make this work, is to store authentication tokens on a database so they can be shared between the two apps.

Disclaimer: I don't have much experience with Rails anymore, so I'm not sure if some of the frameworks like Devise can do something like this out of the box.

## Edit

Got curious and ... google had the answer: http://codetheory.in/rails-devise-omniauth-sso/

Comment: I had seen that post previously when trying to work out how to do this, but maybe its going over my head.. I'm not sure how this syncs the user data? Is the user ID the same across all client apps? Does this allow one app to query user data (avatar/user points etc) in another app?

Comment: @BigJ you'll have a shared DB so yes accessing the same data across all apps are possible as long as you've the auth token. Refer to the overall conceptual flow at the bottom. By User ID if you're referring the the primary key in the DB then yes it's going to be same due to the shared DB. But the session ID will all be different for different apps that basically "remembers" the logged in user. (I'm the author of the article)